# How to create new divs with appended values after XMLHTTP request

Tags: javascript, function, xmlhttprequest

I was wondering if any of you guys would assist me in finding a solution to the problem I am dealing with.

I'm working on a homework assignment for my Webpage Production 2 course based on AJAX.

I already have the XMLHTTP request working well, with everything logging to the console properly, but I want to use the parsed array's values to create new divs for each result.

Here is an example of the non-working code:

```
    let body = document.getElementById('wrapper')
    let obj;

function loaded(){
    if (req.readyState === 4){
           obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
           console.log(obj);
           addToSite();
           }
}
           function addToSite(){
           for (i=0; i<obj.results.length; i++){
                let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
                let newTit = document.createElement('h3');
                body.appendChild(newDiv);
                newDiv.appendChild(newTit);
                let titVal = document.createTextNode(obj.results[i].trackName);
                newTit.appendChild(titVal);
          }
}
```

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: You need one more appendChild which appends the newDiv to the body.

Comment: Fixed issue there, but problem still persists.

Comment: Everything loads fine, but an error pops up every time I try to create a new div.

Comment: the error takes place in the line where I append a new div.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: Check your `#wrapper` is exist or not. Function name is wrong, you define `AddToSite` but you call `addToSite();`

Comment: I fixed that and checked for a wrapper div, which I have, but the issue keeps popping up.